# Is it safe to swap two integers by `a, b = b, a` in golang?

Tags: go, standards, semantics, idioms, correctness

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    a := 1
    b := 2

    fmt.Printf("Before Swap: %v %v\n", a, b)
    a, b = b, a
    fmt.Printf(" After Swap: %v %v\n", a, b)
}
```

The output is:

```
Before Swap: 1 2  
 After Swap: 2 1
```

It looks good. I just wonder:

**Is it safe to swap two integers by** `a, b = b, a` **in golang?**

Comment: Yes, and the language specification is available and easy to read: https://go.dev/ref/spec#Assignment_statements

Comment: Why would it _not_ be safe? What sort of condition are you concerned about when using a legal assignment which is allowed by the compiler?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's safe to swap two variables using:

```golang
a, b = b, a
```

The assignment happens in two steps:

- The right hand side of the assignment is evaluated first.
- Then the evaluated values will be assigned to the left hand side in left-to-right order.

In other words, `a, b = b, a` will be rewritten roughly to:

```golang
tmpB := b
tmpA := a
a = tmpB
b = tmpA
```

That's why the assignment is safe.

---

In fact, the compiler is smart enough to avoid a second temporary variable, so `a, b = b, a` will be rewritten as:

```golang
tmpA := a
a = b
b = tmpA
```

```
$ cat x.go 
package p

func f(a, b int) {
    a, b = b, a
}
$ go tool compile -W x.go

before walk f
.   AS2 tc(1) # x.go:4:7
.   AS2-Lhs
.   .   NAME-p.a esc(no) Class:PPARAM Offset:0 OnStack Used int tc(1) # x.go:3:8
.   .   NAME-p.b esc(no) Class:PPARAM Offset:0 OnStack Used int tc(1) # x.go:3:11
.   AS2-Rhs
.   .   NAME-p.b esc(no) Class:PPARAM Offset:0 OnStack Used int tc(1) # x.go:3:11
.   .   NAME-p.a esc(no) Class:PPARAM Offset:0 OnStack Used int tc(1) # x.go:3:8
after walk f
.   BLOCK # x.go:4:7
.   BLOCK-List
.   .   AS tc(1) # x.go:4:7
.   .   .   NAME-p..autotmp_2 esc(N) Class:PAUTO Offset:0 AutoTemp OnStack Used int tc(1) # x.go:4:7
.   .   .   NAME-p.a esc(no) Class:PPARAM Offset:0 OnStack Used int tc(1) # x.go:3:8
.   .   AS tc(1) # x.go:4:7
.   .   .   NAME-p.a esc(no) Class:PPARAM Offset:0 OnStack Used int tc(1) # x.go:3:8
.   .   .   NAME-p.b esc(no) Class:PPARAM Offset:0 OnStack Used int tc(1) # x.go:3:11
.   .   AS tc(1) # x.go:4:7
.   .   .   NAME-p.b esc(no) Class:PPARAM Offset:0 OnStack Used int tc(1) # x.go:3:11
.   .   .   NAME-p..autotmp_2 esc(N) Class:PAUTO Offset:0 AutoTemp OnStack Used int tc(1) # x.go:4:7
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. When you have same variable type, you can swipe them.

```
i := []int{1, 2, 3, 4}
i[0], i[1], i[2], i[3] = i[3], i[2], i[1], i[0]
// now, i is: []int{4, 3, 2, 1}
// btw, you could also range over slice and swipe them
```

From the [docs](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Assignment_statements)

In assignments, each value must be [assignable](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Assignability) to the type of the operand to which it is assigned, with the following special cases:

1. Any typed value may be assigned to the blank identifier.
2. If an untyped constant is assigned to a variable of interface type or the blank identifier, the constant is first implicitly [converted](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Conversions) to its [default type](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Constants).
3. If an untyped boolean value is assigned to a variable of interface type or the blank identifier, it is first implicitly converted to type bool.

Comment: I'm not sure your quote explains why swapping two variables in assignment is safe. The correct quote should be the paragraph which describe the order of evaluation and assignment.